# How to create multidimensional json object in a loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using the following code to search through a folder structure and write all package names and versions into a string.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import glob
import json

repo_list = ["core", "multilib", "nonfree", "testing"] 

for i in repo_list:
    print(i)
    for name in glob.glob('../' + i +'/*/spkgbuild'): 
        package_name = ''
        package_version = ''
        temp_json = ''
        package = open(name,'r')
        Lines = package.readlines()
        for line in Lines:
            if(line.strip().startswith('name')):
                package_name = line.strip()[5:]
            if(line.strip().startswith('version')):
                package_version = line.strip()[8:]
            if(package_name != '' and package_version != ''):
                temp_json = {package_name: {"version": package_version}}
```

From this I actually want to have the following JSON object later:

```json
{
  "core": {
    "package_name": {
      "version": "1.1.1"
    },
    "package_name2": {
      "version": "1.1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck writing the object now, can you help me there?

Comment: you know that what you described is not json array but json object as it has keys and curly brackets

Comment: change `temp_json = {package_name: {"version": package_version}}` to `temp_json={}; temp_json[package_name] = {"version": package_version}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob
import json

repo_list = ["core", "multilib", "nonfree", "testing"] 

json_ = {}
for i in repo_list:
    print(i)
    for name in glob.glob('../' + i +'/*/spkgbuild'): 
        package_name = ''
        package_version = ''
        package = open(name,'r')
        Lines = package.readlines()
        for line in Lines:
            if(line.strip().startswith('name')):
                package_name = line.strip()[5:]
            if(line.strip().startswith('version')):
                package_version = line.strip()[8:]
            if(package_name != '' and package_version != ''):
                json_[package_name] = {"version": package_version}
                package_name = ""
                package_version = "" 
printl(json)
```

just insert all data to one dictionary and you have it all together, now i dont know if you have multiple versions and names per file so just in case I am also reseting values